# What is the proper pattern to intercept requests and manage tokens and token renewals using axios.interceptors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, interceptor

I might need some help how to use axios interceptors here. This is a part of the login screen. I want to have the interceptor refresh the token when its missing or its expired. I am not even sure it is the right place to have this code as token refresh will needs to be happening after the login too.
I have two axios instances. One for the API and one for auth0. I would need a way to connect them so they work together and reliable.

```
import token from "../../network/axios-auth0";
import client from "../../network/axios-client";  

//Gets token and updates the redux token value
getToken() {
    token.post("token", {
      client_id: config.clientId,
      client_secret: config.clientSecret,
      audience: config.clientAudience,
      grant_type: "client_credentials"
    })
      .then(response => {
        this.props.onUpdateToken(response.data.access_token);
        this.getGroup(response.data.access_token)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

//Gets token from redux and gets data
  getGroup() {
    client.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
      //call getToken() for new token or check old token
      return config;
    }, function (error) {
      // Do something with request error
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });

    client.get("groups/5ca21cd1cb9134222e397f14", {data: {}, headers: {"Authorization":"Bearer " + this.props.bearerToken}})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }


  onLoginPress(){
    this.getToken();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput placeholder={"user"}/>
        <TextInput placeholder={"pass"}/>
        <Button title={"login"} onPress={() => this.onLoginPress()}/>
      </View>
    )
  }

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    token: state.values.token
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onUpdateToken: (value: string) => dispatch(updateToken(value))
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginScreen);
```

I mean the interceptor will be needed in every axios call (to prevent a request getting stuck because of old token) So it would be best to attach it to the instance. But then I don't know how to update the token in redux from the file where the instance is defined. It's probably not the best practice either. Here is one of the 2 instances defined.

```
import axios from "axios"
import config from "../config"


const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: config.apiUrl,
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  }
});
client.defaults.headers.get["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

export default client;
```

How would one do this professionally. I don't want to copy the interceptor for each call in the app.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: If I remember correctly no, there is a library that is supposed to make the process easier but I encountered an error there too. I might give it an extra try.
https://github.com/Flyrell/axios-auth-refresh